Modify a column in a data.table: replace string by the last valid token
Trying to modify a data.table column by replacing a string to the last valid token, leaving "NA" when the last token is missing.
Reproducible example:
input_DT <- structure(list(Team = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2"), Player = c("T1.P1", 
"T1.P2", "T1.P3", "T1.P4", "T1.P5", "T1.P1", "T1.P2", "T1.P3", 
"T1.P4", "T1.P5", "T2.P1", "T2.P2", "T2.P3", "T2.P4", "T2.P5"
), Year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), Str = c("a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a bin", 
"a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a 3 2", "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a north", 
"a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|an", "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a c d", 
"a bin|a north|an|a bin", "a bin|a north|an", "a bin|a north|an|a north", 
"a bin|a north|an|an", "a bin|a north|an", "an|bin|4eight|12|an", 
"an|bin|4eight|12", "an|bin|4eight|12|bin", "an|bin|4eight|12|4eight", 
"an|bin|4eight|12|12")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))

> print(input_DT)
      Team Player  Year                                  Str
    <char> <char> <int>                               <char>
 1:     T1  T1.P1  2011   a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a bin
 2:     T1  T1.P2  2011   a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a 3 2
 3:     T1  T1.P3  2011 a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a north
 4:     T1  T1.P4  2011      a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|an
 5:     T1  T1.P5  2011   a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a c d
 6:     T1  T1.P1  2012               a bin|a north|an|a bin
 7:     T1  T1.P2  2012                     a bin|a north|an
 8:     T1  T1.P3  2012             a bin|a north|an|a north
 9:     T1  T1.P4  2012                  a bin|a north|an|an
10:     T1  T1.P5  2012                     a bin|a north|an
11:     T2  T2.P1  2011                  an|bin|4eight|12|an
12:     T2  T2.P2  2011                     an|bin|4eight|12
13:     T2  T2.P3  2011                 an|bin|4eight|12|bin
14:     T2  T2.P4  2011              an|bin|4eight|12|4eight
15:     T2  T2.P5  2011                  an|bin|4eight|12|12

output_DT <- structure(list(Team = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2"), Player = c("T1.P1", 
"T1.P2", "T1.P3", "T1.P4", "T1.P5", "T1.P1", "T1.P2", "T1.P3", 
"T1.P4", "T1.P5", "T2.P1", "T2.P2", "T2.P3", "T2.P4", "T2.P5"
), Year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 
2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), Var = c("a bin", 
"a 3 2", "a north", "an", "a c d", "a bin", "", "a north", "an", 
"", "an", "", "bin", "4eight", "12")), row.names = c(NA, -15L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

> print(output_DT)
      Team Player  Year     Var
    <char> <char> <int>  <char>
 1:     T1  T1.P1  2011   a bin
 2:     T1  T1.P2  2011   a 3 2
 3:     T1  T1.P3  2011 a north
 4:     T1  T1.P4  2011      an
 5:     T1  T1.P5  2011   a c d
 6:     T1  T1.P1  2012   a bin
 7:     T1  T1.P2  2012      NA
 8:     T1  T1.P3  2012 a north
 9:     T1  T1.P4  2012      an
10:     T1  T1.P5  2012      NA
11:     T2  T2.P1  2011      an
12:     T2  T2.P2  2011      NA
13:     T2  T2.P3  2011     bin
14:     T2  T2.P4  2011  4eight
15:     T2  T2.P5  2011      12


Remarks:

In input_DT, the string in "Str" column contains all tokens in each "Team" per "Year", concatenized by "|";
The last token in each string in "Str" column (input_DT) is the valid token to be kept in "Var" column (output_DT), except when the string doesn't have the max string "length" (in this case, meaning the max number of tokens) by team and year (the last token is missing). In this case, the "Var" is NA (see rows 7, 10 and 12 in ouput_DT);

What i have tried:
output_DT$Var <- 
  input_DT[,
           data.table::fifelse(
             stringr::str_count(input_DT$Str,"\\|")==max(stringr::str_count(input_DT$Str,"\\|")),
             stringr::word(input_DT$Str,
                  sep = stringr::fixed("|"),-1
             ),NA_character_
           )
  ]

> print(output_DT)
    Team Player Year     Var
 1:   T1  T1.P1 2011   a bin
 2:   T1  T1.P2 2011   a 3 2
 3:   T1  T1.P3 2011 a north
 4:   T1  T1.P4 2011      an
 5:   T1  T1.P5 2011   a c d
 6:   T1  T1.P1 2012    <NA>
 7:   T1  T1.P2 2012    <NA>
 8:   T1  T1.P3 2012    <NA>
 9:   T1  T1.P4 2012    <NA>
10:   T1  T1.P5 2012    <NA>
11:   T2  T2.P1 2011    <NA>
12:   T2  T2.P2 2011    <NA>
13:   T2  T2.P3 2011    <NA>
14:   T2  T2.P4 2011    <NA>
15:   T2  T2.P5 2011    <NA> 


The way i tried, the max string "length" (max tokens in a string) is based in all strings in "Str" column, not in the number of tokens in the strings by each Team and Year.
Thanks in advance.

Is a solution with multiple steps acceptable?
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
input_DT <- structure(list(Team = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
                                    "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2"), 
                           Player = c("T1.P1", "T1.P2", "T1.P3", "T1.P4", "T1.P5", "T1.P1", "T1.P2", "T1.P3", 
                                      "T1.P4", "T1.P5", "T2.P1", "T2.P2", "T2.P3", "T2.P4", "T2.P5"
                           ), Year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 
                                       2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), 
                           Str = c("a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a bin", "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a 3 2", "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a north", 
                                   "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|an", "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a c d", 
                                   "a bin|a north|an|a bin", "a bin|a north|an", "a bin|a north|an|a north", 
                                   "a bin|a north|an|an", "a bin|a north|an", "an|bin|4eight|12|an", 
                                   "an|bin|4eight|12", "an|bin|4eight|12|bin", "an|bin|4eight|12|4eight", 
                                   "an|bin|4eight|12|12")), 
                      row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

CountPipes <- input_DT[, .(maxPipes = max(str_count(Str, "\\|"))), c("Team", "Year")]
input_DT2 <- merge(input_DT, CountPipes)
input_DT2[, Pipes := str_count(Str, "\\|")]
input_DT2[, Var := fifelse(Pipes == maxPipes, str_extract(Str, "[^|]+$"), NA)]
input_DT2
#> Key: <Team, Year>
#>       Team  Year Player                                  Str maxPipes Pipes
#>     <char> <int> <char>                               <char>    <int> <int>
#>  1:     T1  2011  T1.P1   a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a bin        5     5
#>  2:     T1  2011  T1.P2   a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a 3 2        5     5
#>  3:     T1  2011  T1.P3 a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a north        5     5
#>  4:     T1  2011  T1.P4      a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|an        5     5
#>  5:     T1  2011  T1.P5   a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a c d        5     5
#>  6:     T1  2012  T1.P1               a bin|a north|an|a bin        3     3
#>  7:     T1  2012  T1.P2                     a bin|a north|an        3     2
#>  8:     T1  2012  T1.P3             a bin|a north|an|a north        3     3
#>  9:     T1  2012  T1.P4                  a bin|a north|an|an        3     3
#> 10:     T1  2012  T1.P5                     a bin|a north|an        3     2
#> 11:     T2  2011  T2.P1                  an|bin|4eight|12|an        4     4
#> 12:     T2  2011  T2.P2                     an|bin|4eight|12        4     3
#> 13:     T2  2011  T2.P3                 an|bin|4eight|12|bin        4     4
#> 14:     T2  2011  T2.P4              an|bin|4eight|12|4eight        4     4
#> 15:     T2  2011  T2.P5                  an|bin|4eight|12|12        4     4
#>         Var
#>      <char>
#>  1:   a bin
#>  2:   a 3 2
#>  3: a north
#>  4:      an
#>  5:   a c d
#>  6:   a bin
#>  7:    <NA>
#>  8: a north
#>  9:      an
#> 10:    <NA>
#> 11:      an
#> 12:    <NA>
#> 13:     bin
#> 14:  4eight
#> 15:      12

Created on 2024-10-17 with reprex v2.1.1
Additional Solution after the OP's comment
Here is a more elegant solution.
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:lubridate':
#> 
#>     hour, isoweek, mday, minute, month, quarter, second, wday, week,
#>     yday, year
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     transpose

input_DT <- data.table(Team = c("T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
                                "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2"), 
                       Player = c("T1.P1", "T1.P2", "T1.P3", "T1.P4", "T1.P5", "T1.P1", "T1.P2", "T1.P3", 
                                  "T1.P4", "T1.P5", "T2.P1", "T2.P2", "T2.P3", "T2.P4", "T2.P5"
                       ), Year = c(2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2012L, 2012L, 
                                   2012L, 2012L, 2012L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L, 2011L), 
                       Str = c("a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a bin", "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a 3 2", "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a north", 
                               "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|an", "a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a c d", 
                               "a bin|a north|an|a bin", "a bin|a north|an", "a bin|a north|an|a north", 
                               "a bin|a north|an|an", "a bin|a north|an", "an|bin|4eight|12|an", 
                               "an|bin|4eight|12", "an|bin|4eight|12|bin", "an|bin|4eight|12|4eight", 
                               "an|bin|4eight|12|12"))

input_DT[, Var := fifelse(str_count(Str, "\\|") == max(str_count(Str, "\\|")), str_extract(Str, "[^|]+$"), NA), 
         c("Team", "Year")]
input_DT
#>       Team Player  Year                                  Str     Var
#>     <char> <char> <int>                               <char>  <char>
#>  1:     T1  T1.P1  2011   a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a bin   a bin
#>  2:     T1  T1.P2  2011   a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a 3 2   a 3 2
#>  3:     T1  T1.P3  2011 a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a north a north
#>  4:     T1  T1.P4  2011      a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|an      an
#>  5:     T1  T1.P5  2011   a bin|a 3 2|a north|an|a c d|a c d   a c d
#>  6:     T1  T1.P1  2012               a bin|a north|an|a bin   a bin
#>  7:     T1  T1.P2  2012                     a bin|a north|an    <NA>
#>  8:     T1  T1.P3  2012             a bin|a north|an|a north a north
#>  9:     T1  T1.P4  2012                  a bin|a north|an|an      an
#> 10:     T1  T1.P5  2012                     a bin|a north|an    <NA>
#> 11:     T2  T2.P1  2011                  an|bin|4eight|12|an      an
#> 12:     T2  T2.P2  2011                     an|bin|4eight|12    <NA>
#> 13:     T2  T2.P3  2011                 an|bin|4eight|12|bin     bin
#> 14:     T2  T2.P4  2011              an|bin|4eight|12|4eight  4eight
#> 15:     T2  T2.P5  2011                  an|bin|4eight|12|12      12

Created on 2024-10-18 with reprex v2.1.1

It certainly helps. But i'm still looking for a neater way, maybe with settings keys to data.table. The center point consists in restrict the calculations (j) intervals and index it to the key. But thanks anyway

I appended another possible solution.
